# Weird string behaviour, replaces parts of itself

Tags: c#, string

I can't seem to wrap my head around this. How can this become:

```
string.Format(@"https://www.dropbox.com/s/{0}/{1}?dl=1", dl[rndIndex], rndIndex);
```

this:

> /3?dl=1/www.dropbox.com/s/s8ghw2mvld2jg0l

It's like taking the part after {0} ,shifts it to the front and overrides the existing string...
Does anyone know what's going on here?

This is the entire code (pseudo):

```
string[] dl = new string[] { "...", "...", "..." };
int rndIndex = rnd.Next(0, dl.Length);
Console.WriteLine(string.Format(@"https://www.dropbox.com/s/{0}/{1}?dl=1", dl[rndIndex], rndIndex));
```

There's nothing wrong with dl[] and rndIndex, checked both of them.

This fixed the problem:

```
            string s = dl[rndIndex];
            s = s.Replace(((char)13).ToString(), "");
```

Which is what you suggested.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: How does the code look like? Where are you assigning the result? Are you reusing variables? By itself `string.Format` cannot do what you are describing.

Comment: @PhilH: C#, obviously.

Comment: At first look `Format` can't be the source of problem. You should provide more code and specify language.

Comment: It’s as if `dl[rndIndex]` contains a carriage return that places the cursor back to the beginning and then the `/{1}?dl=1` overwrites the start of the URL.

Comment: Your pseudo code dos not show the problem. Make a small but complete program and then post it.

Comment: @poke Is there an ASCII value for this?

Comment: There's nothing in your code that would cause the error. As `poke` suggested, it could be that your `dl` array contains a string with `\r` inside it. Try escaping all string elements in `dl` by adding `@` to the beginning of the string (e.g. `@"myString"`)

Comment: Sample code is work fine for me. so there is no issue in it. please post more code here. special what is the content of `dl`

Comment: just a question , why do you string.format inside console.writeline which already support the formatting style?

Comment: @Stefano Probably because the console output isn’t meant to be there in the final application but just for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way the it replaces the beginning of the URL, it seems that `dl[rndIndex]` contains a carriage return which places the cursor back to the beginning of the line and then overwrites the `https:/` part of the URL (which fits as `/3?dl=1` has the same length).

So your formatted string actually looks like this:

```
"https://www.dropbox.com/s/s8ghw2mvld2jg0l\r/3?dl=1"
                                          ^^
                                    carriage return
```

Now when that is printed to a console which supports carriage returns, it will print the first part `https://www.dropbox.com/s/s8ghw2mvld2jg0l` then set the cursor back to the beginning and print the rest `/3?dl=1`.

So you should basically strip out all carriage returns from the string first. In any way it seems as if your `dl` array does not contain what you expect it to do.

Comment: The type of rndIndex is **int**

Comment: @noobob So? `rndIndex` is only used to get a random element out of the `dl` array – and that’s where the carriage return is.

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce the exact problem by @poke's comment:

```
string.Format("https://www.dropbox.com/s/{0}/{1}?dl=1", "hfjdhfjdh\r", 30)
```

will output:

```
/30?dl=1www.dropbox.com/s/hfjdhfjdh
```

The problem is a carriage return or new line character in your array elements.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying your fragment as follows:

```
string[] dl = new string[] { "...", "...", "..." };
int rndIndex = 1;    // rnd.Next(0, dl.Length);
Console.WriteLine(string.Format(@"https://www.dropbox.com/s/{0}/{1}?dl=1", dl[rndIndex], rndIndex));
```

Gives a correct answer.

```
https://www.dropbox.com/s/.../1?dl=1
```

So, two thoughts:

- It's a data dependent problem
- Should the random function not read `rnd.Next(0, dl.Length-1)`

Comment: The upper limit of Random.Next is exclusive, where the lower is inclusive, so this should work just fine